# mendelson opensource AS2 getting connection exception: connection failure

Tags: java, sql

I am not a java developer Here we have an open source AS2 server. But we are getting frequently some exceptions like below.

```
A problem occurred on the AS2 server instance. Most of these notifications are not critical for your AS2 system status. If the related transaction is on status "green" you could be sure that the transaction has been finished. Anyway please have a look at your AS2 system to see what happened there.

Category: SQLTransientConnectionException
Message: connection exception: connection failure: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)

org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
de.mendelson.util.database.DebuggableConnection.prepareStatement(DebuggableConnection.java:156)
de.mendelson.comm.as2.sendorder.SendOrderAccessDB.getNext(SendOrderAccessDB.java:180)
de.mendelson.comm.as2.sendorder.SendOrderReceiver.run(SendOrderReceiver.java:102)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So what could be the reason to get this kind of errors? Any idea about this?